# How to update multiple rows in one table using an aggregate query on another table

Tags: sql

I have SQL update query problem.  I would like to be able to update one table using the results of a query against another table.     Here is a simple example to show what I would like to do.

I have two tables:

```
TABLE1                      

ID     COUNT                                 
1       0         
2       0
3       0

Table2

ID
1
1
1
2


select id,count(*) from table2 group by id;

ID    COUNT
1       3
2       1
```

I can update one row at a time using this syntax:

```
update table1 set count=(select count(*) from table2 where id=1 group by id) where id=1;
```

What I would like is to be able to update all rows with one single sql statement so that the result would be:

```
TABLE1                      

ID     COUNT                                 
1       3         
2       1
3       0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which database system are you using? We could talk about SQL standards, but in a practical sense, that wouldn't help you much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this might work for you:

```
update table1 
set count=
   (select count(*) 
    from table2 
    where table2.id=table1.id)
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are using SQL Server I would try using a cursor http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx

Comment: Absolutely not. Server-side cursors in SQL Server are abysmally slow. Never use them unless there is no alternative.

Comment: Ahh, thank you for explaining the downvote. I shall remember that.